# Почему теряется качество гифки при вставке на HTML страницу?

Tags: html

Загружаю в тег img gif-анимацию, по прямой ссылке отображается в полном качестве, а в html-странице качество становится убогим. Почему?

Код, который я использую

```
    <img src="loading.gif"></img>
```

Comment: Код на html странице покажите? Вы её сжимаете по ширине\высоте?

Comment: Приведите код HTML страницы. Возможно, меняется размер и включается сглаживание.

Comment: добавьте свой код, посмотрите как создать [mcve], и тогда, имея ваш пример, можно догадаться в чем у вас возникла проблема, без кода это невозможно

Comment: Используйте svg =)

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="http://website.com/image.gif" width="320" height="240" />
```

`http://website.com/image.gif` - следует заменить на вашу "прямую ссылку" с изображением...